# Change default scope for all bindings "to" a particular class

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

Is there any way to set the default scope for all bindings "to" a particular class. For instance if I have the following:

```
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface1>.To<MySingletonClass>();
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface2>.To<MySingletonClass>();
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface3>.To<MySingletonClass>();
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface4>.To<MySingletonClass>();
```

I'd like all of these to be singleton scoped by default. And all of the following to be request scoped by default:

```
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface1>.To<MyClass>();
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface2>.To<MyClass>();
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface3>.To<MyClass>();
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface4>.To<MyClass>();
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm using DI to use in-memory data storage when running in debug locally and then EF to connect to a SQL database in production. I don't want my EF context to be singleton, but per request memory storage is pretty useless :) I realize I could just append .InSingletonScope() to all four lines in the first example, but I was just wondering if there was something cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `.InXXXScope()` methods boil down to an `InScope( callback)` method. Or you could make an extension method which does one or the other depending on a parameter.

Ninject.Extensions.Conventions can be useful when doing stuff like this (and it has examples of binding multiple interfaces and/or all interfaces as you are doing).

Most importantly - don't use Ninject in tests. I reckon you're missing an abstraction if you need to do loads of wiring like this to effect an important switch like this. Perhaps AutoFixture or similar has a role to play in your environment?

Comment: Haven't heard of AutoFixture before, but I'll have to check it out. Thanks!